# custom javascript objects as properties of other custom javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I want to create some custom javascript objects some of which have properties which are other objects.  I'm not sure what the syntax would be to do this.  My pseudo code is below with the idea that I have a person object and an order object.  The order object has a property that I want to be of the person object type.  Is this possible in javascript and if so, can someone give me a basic example?  Thanks.

```
var person {
    name: "John",
    gender: "M",
    age: 3  
}

var order {
    customer: person, /*the property name is customer but of type person - is this possible?*/
    total: 100  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost correct; all you need is to include some '='

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    gender: "M",
    age: 3  
}

var order = {
    customer: person, /*the property name is customer but of type person - is this possible?*/
    total: 100  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider constructors:

```
function Person( name, gender, age ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}

function Order( customer, total ) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.total = total;
}
```

Usage:

```
var person1 = new Person( 'John', 'M', 3 );
var order1 = new Order( person1, 100 );
```

The constructors act as classes. You invoke them via `new` to create new instances (persons and orders).

Comment: +1 for the O.O. solution... but if I may, I'd suggest to use a framework (like Mootools) instead of using the native JS O.O., basically is the same but it save you the headache of having complex types as attributes. In this example, if you do `person1.age = 5;` you'd also change the order1 variable and it might cause you some troubles later if you're not careful

Comment: @pleasedontbelong It doesn't change the `order1` object. This object has a `customer` property which is a reference to the person associated with the order. A specific person (e.g. `'John'` in this example) is represented by exactly one object. All orders made by that person have a reference to that object. I'm not sure how this design pattern could lead to problems later on.

Comment: =P srry i was thinking about this http://www.copypastecode.com/165660/ but in this example they set the properties directly in the prototype and not in the constructor (like you did).. i forgot that `this` in the constructor points to the instance and doesn't affect the prototype

Comment: @pleasedontbelong That's why you generally want to only have functions in the prototype (the instance methods which are shared by all instances). Instance-specific information is assigned to the instance directly or bound to its privileged methods through closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    gender: "M",
    age: 3  
};

var order = {
    customer: person,
    total: 100  
};
```

This also passes in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  You were missing '=' signs.

Answer (score 0):

You code is nearly fine (missing the = to assign the anonymous object to the variable):

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    gender: "M",
    age: 3  
};

var order = {
    customer: person, /*the property name is customer but of type person - is this possible?*/
    total: 100  
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D7u3x/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, thats pretty much it. Your syntax is a little off, but only slightly.

Here is your example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/rKCdL/)